# Facebook Test Users Friends of Friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created an app and added some test users to it on the app Facebook page. Then I have make some friends linking on them.

When I query one user friends of friends, after I have set the app visibility for all the test users to friends of friends, I cannot see the friends of friends.

The access token that I am using is the one from the test users page, so it is related to the app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not get “friends of friends” via API _at all_.

Comment: No? I have tested with my real user and a friend user and I can see his friends of friends within an application.

Comment: What specific API requests are you talking about then?

Comment: The Graph API with a iOS access token. I'm requesting the user friends that has the app installed using: user_id/friends URL in the Graph API.

Comment: Then that user has to have granted `user_friends` permission to the app – and the friends as well. If user A is friends with user B, and only A has granted `user_friends` permission – then requesting `/A/friends` will not show user B.

Comment: Yes I have already done that. Let me check again and I will be back to you.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to either specify the `user_friends` permission when creating the test users already, or have the text users go through the login flow and grant that permission then.

Comment: Okay, I have re-checked all the 3 test users that I have for the application and all of them have Friends of Friends visibility for the application and also have the user_friends permission enabled. Could it be that for test users, their friends of friends are never visible?

Comment: Again, there is no way to see “friends of friends” via the API. All you can see is the direct friends of the user that you are making the query for.

Comment: Okay, I will try again with the real users I have tested to see if I can confirm your response. Thanks